# jQuery not adding class to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a class to the body when someone is viewing the page on a mobile device. I have got the mobile detection down, but for some reason jQuery won't add a class to the body tag. I am stumped as to why it isn't working. I get the alert with 2nd but no mobile class.

```
(function () {
        var NO_REDIRECT = 'noredirect'; // cookie to prevent redirect
        // I only want to effect phones
        if (isMobile.any) {
                alert('1st')
                // Only redirect if the user didn't previously choose
                // to explicitly view the full site. This is validated
                // by checking if a "noredirect" cookie exists
                if ( document.cookie.indexOf(NO_REDIRECT) === -1 ) {
                    alert('2nd');
                    $(document.body).addClass('mobile');
                }
            }
        })();
```

Comment: You'll still need a DOM ready handler if that code is in the head section

Comment: Works for me. Please provide additional steps to recreate problem.

Comment: Javascript is run immediately when it is parsed on the page.  If it is before the <body> then it won't find the element to add the class to because it hasn't been loaded yet.   Wrap it in a `ready()` function or move it so that the html is on the page when the javascript is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DOM may not be ready by the time you execute `$(document.body).addClass('mobile');`

Try to wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code goes here
});
```

Comment: Oh geez, you're right. I completely forgot about that. It's been alittle while since I've done development.